# user email (correctly) shows as verified on frontend but not backend in modified firenotes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

To address the close votes, all I'm asking for here is how to check that a user has verified their email in python on app engine.

The relevant bit of backend python code is:

```
id_token = request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ').pop()
claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(
        id_token, HTTP_REQUEST, MY_PROJECT_ID)

if not claims:
    return 'Unauthorized', 401
logging.warn('email verified? {}'.format(claims['email_verified'])) # always False
```

---

Original post:

I'm messing around with the [firenotes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes) example code. I've disabled everything but email log in, and want to make sure on the backend that the user has verified their email address. Inside [`frontend/main.js`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes/frontend/main.js), checking `user.emailVerified` gives me the correct value.

However, this is not the case inside of [`backend/main.py`.
Inside of `list_notes()`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes/backend/main.py#L78) if I add a `logging.warn(claims)` I invariably see a key-value pair `u'email_verified': False`. I've tried restarting the server after verifying to avoid caching issues (which if they exist would still suck) but can't seem to actually detect whether the user has clicked the verification link in their email on the backend.

Is there something I need to add or configure to get the backend to be able to see (or maybe check for) email verification?

Comment: I see your point, seems like inconsistent Data between `user`, `idToken` and `claim`. You have to trust the token is signed by Firebase. I could imagine the result `claim` don't know how the user is authenticatet or it's a feature not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into exactly the same issue. The problem seems to be that the attributes associated with a particular firebase token become stale, and this problem only affects token-based verification on the back end. **Solution: If the user signs out and back in after email verification, then the information is updated.**

More precisely, here is the current behavior. In Javascript, on the front end, `firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified` is correctly true immediately after user verifies email and the page is refreshed. However, when the corresponding firebase token is sent to the server via `user.getIdToken().then(function(token) { sendToServer(token); })`, and then verified using Google App engine python library on the back end as `uinfo = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(token, google.auth.transport.requests.Request())`, then `uinfo['email_verified']` remains `False` until user re-signs in and an updated token is issued.